# Trying to connect two SQL Server databases

Tags: sql-server, connectivity

I have been trying to connect to a SQL Server instance. When I use the IP address, it connects. But when I use the server name, it doesn't. The main reason why I need to use the name is because I want to setup replication.

This is the error I am getting:

[image: "Failed To Connect" error]

Any ideas on what I could be missing?

I am in a Windows environment and I used the machine IP. Firewall is opened for port 1433 TCP.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like name resolution is not working. Do you have a DNS server? If not, you may have to make entries in the `hosts` files on both computers to enable name resolution. The hosts file on Windows is at `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Try using FQDN. If the server is in a different domain, and a host record is not created in DNS, this would be required to resolve. You could also try creating an alias in SQL Server Configuration Manager.